# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm working on a project wherein I'm using Realm database, now I'm trying to fetch a value from a database, its working fine 3-4 times then code is crashing.
The error message is as follows

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: in.mumbaitravellers.mtleaders, PID: 22340
>                     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 3 > 3
>                         at io.realm.internal.TableView.nativeGetSourceRowIndex(Native Method)
>                         at io.realm.internal.TableView.getSourceRowIndex(TableView.java:161)
>                         at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:114)
>                         at in.mumbaitravellers.mtleaders.adapters.ExpenseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpenseAdapter.java:55)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
>                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreog
>   W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.933ms

The code snippet is as follows:

```
public class ExpenseAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapater<Expense> {

final Context context;
private Realm realm;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ExpenseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflate a new card view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expense_recycler_view, parent, false);
    // view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    return new CardViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    realm = RealmController.getInstance().getRealm();

    final Expense expense = getItem(position);
    final Tour tour = new Tour();
    final CardViewHolder holder = (CardViewHolder) viewHolder;
    String s = "";

    RealmResults<Tour> r = realm.where(Tour.class).findAll();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    s = r.get(position).getEventId();
    realm.commitTransaction();


    holder.textExpense.setText(expense.getAmount() + " E: " + expense.getEventId());
    holder.textDescription.setText(expense.getDescription() + " T: " + s);

    holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_new_expense, null);
            final EditText editAmount = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_expense);
            final EditText editDescription = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edtxt_description);

            editAmount.setText(expense.getAmount());
            editDescription.setText(expense.getDescription());

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(content)
                    .setTitle("Edit Event")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            RealmResults<Expense> results = realm.where(Expense.class).findAll();

                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            results.get(position).setAmount(editAmount.getText().toString());
                            results.get(position).setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());

                            realm.commitTransaction();

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (getRealmAdapter() != null) {
        return getRealmAdapter().getCount();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView card;
    public TextView textExpense;
    public TextView textDescription;

    public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // standard view holder pattern with Butterknife view injection
        super(itemView);

        card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_expense);
        textExpense = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_amount);
        textDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_description);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: does your ide show you in which line the error occures? to me it seems that line #31 (in your code) might be responsible for your error. since this is the only line that retrieves any data from the realm instance

Comment: @Radinator error is occuring in these lines
     RealmResults<Tour> r = realm.where(Tour.class).findAll();
     realm.beginTransaction();
     s = r.get(position).getEventId();
     realm.commitTransaction();

Comment: then try to debug your app and print r.Count() I think your problem is that the value in position is bigger than the amount of items in the **RealmResult<Tour>**

Comment: @Radinator technically he just has to not call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` manually

Answer (score 3):

This is why:

```
RealmResults<Expense> results = realm.where(Expense.class).findAll();
realm.beginTransaction();
results.get(position).setAmount(editAmount.getText().toString());
results.get(position).setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
realm.commitTransaction();
notifyDataSetChanged(); // <--------- this causes the crash
```

Problems:

1.) if you manipulate a result set in a transaction, then you should do the query inside the transaction

```
realm.beginTransaction();
RealmResults<Expense> results = realm.where(Expense.class).findAll();
```

2.) You should avoid creating unnecessary proxies, you should obtain the element only once.

```
Expense expense = results.get(position);
expense.setAmount(editAmount.getText().toString());
expense.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
```

**3.)** since 0.89.0, (but up to 3.0.0), RealmResults are updated only on the next event loop, after which `RealmChangeListener` is called. This is managed automatically by `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, which means if you do UI-thread local commits (you shouldn't, but you can), then you should **NOT** call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` manually, you should register a `RealmChangeListener` and call it from there (this is managed internally by `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`).

So basically, **remove the line `notifyDataSetChanged()`**.

---

Also I see you have a `RealmController.getInstance()` call, I guess you used [this guide from AndroidHive](http://androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/) as basis for your Realm-driven application.

That guide is outdated garbage, I recommend using mine:

[How to use Realm for Android like a champ, and how to tell if you're doing it wrong](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)

Along with the corresponding [source example](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example).